# EXCEL - Compare Two SETS of Columns, Find What doesn't match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following spreadsheet:

[image]

Without listing one by one all the versions of what I've tried without success, let me just explain what I want to do: For each row of columns A through D, I want to see which of columns F through I are NOT in the first set. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to the `FILTER` function?

Comment: *"I want to see"* . Can you define that? How does your expected result look like? Conditional formatting?

Comment: To above point - would also be good if your sample data covered all possible outcomes. Right now, I don't see any of your values in right data set that are present in the left.

Comment: Ah, JvdV, I see your point. Sorry, new to Excel here. And urdearboy, ok, sure, then to answer both: in column K, it would say "Not matched" whenever the second set for that row is not in the first set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a couple of helper columns with `CONCATENATE()` and then use `COUNTIF()`

For example on cell `E2` I'd do:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,B2,C2,D2)
```

and then drag it down.

Same on cell `J2`:

```
=CONCATENATE(F2,G2,H2,I2)
```

Then on cell K2 you can count how many times the item is found in the first set and if it's 0 means is NOT IN THE FIRST SET:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(E:E,J2)=0,"NOT IN FIRST SET","")
```